# How to turn Windows 10 PC as SMTP server?

Tags: technical-indicator

I want to configure my window system as a mail server. Please let me if anybody knows how to configure windows 10 as a mail server. I have an ec2 window instance.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there are a plenty of videos, I hope you found this one useful, :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q4S_6pmPoA